# My function is not iterating over a loop and I can't find the problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a Function that does the Newton-Raphson root finding for multiple variables (dx = -Jinv^-1 * F), but it won't iterate over a loop continuously (ie output won't become the next input for next iteration). Does anyone see the issue?

PS. I'm trying to code it without using any of the built in matrix functions so those solutions won't apply here.

```
# Multivariable Root Finding via Newton Raphson


# import necessary functions
import numpy as np

# define array function for f1 and f2
x = np.arange(-3,3,.01)

def f1(x):
    return 2*(x[0]**3) - 6*(x[0]*(x[1]**2)) - 1

def f2(x):
    return -2*(x[1]**3) + 6*(x[1]*(x[0]**2)) + 3

# define matrix F(x) 2x1
def F(x_vec): 
    return [f1(x_vec),f2(x_vec)]

#print(F([2,3]))


# Create Inverse Jacobian 2x2

# InvJacobian Upper Left
def JUL(x):
    return (6*x[0]**2 - 6*x[1]**2)/((6*x[0]**2 - 6*x[1]**2)**2 + 144*(x[0]**2)*(x[1]**2))

# InvJacobian Upper Right
def JUR(x):
    return (12*x[0]*x[1])/((6*x[0]**2 - 6*x[1]**2)**2 + 144*(x[0]**2)*(x[1]**2))

# InvJacobian Lower Left
def JLL(x):
    return (-12*x[0]*x[1])/((6*x[0]**2 - 6*x[1]**2)**2 + 144*(x[0]**2)*(x[1]**2))

# InvJacobian Lower Left
def JLR(x):
    return (6*x[0]**2 - 6*x[1]**2)/((6*x[0]**2 - 6*x[1]**2)**2 + 144*(x[0]**2)*(x[1]**2))

# Combine all Jacobian into Matrix
def Jinv(x_vec):
    return [JUL(x_vec),JUR(x_vec),JLL(x_vec),JLR(x_vec)]


# Create Newton Raphson Functon

def rf_newton2d(F_system, Jinv_system, x_vec0, tol, maxiter):
    # let ou be the starting array x_vec0
    ou = x_vec0
    i = 0
    err = 10**-4
    

    # F*Jinv should output a 2x1 matrix
    while err > tol and i <= maxiter:
        F_system = F(ou)
        Jinv_system = Jinv(ou)
        # w is the [0] position of the 2x1 output matrix
        w = F_system[0]*Jinv_system[0] + F_system[1]*Jinv_system[1]
    
        # z is the [1] position of the 2x1 output
        z = F_system[0]*Jinv_system[2] + F_system[1]*Jinv_system[3]
    
        # u is the output matrix of F*Jinv
        u = [w,z]
    
        # out is the new array involving u + ou
        out = [ou[0] + u[0],ou[1] +u[1]]
    
        #define nu as out
        nu = out
    
        # let nu be the ou for the next iteration
        ou = nu
    
        #run continuous iterations
        i += 1
    
        return nu

print(rf_newton2d(F([x_vec0]),Jinv([x_vec0]),[2,3],10**-5, 5))
```

Comment: Is the line: ‘return nu’ indented too much?

Answer (score 1):

`return` statements in a function immediately stop the function and continue running the main code from where the function was called. It looks to me like the `return` statement in the `while` loop is not supposed to be in the `while` loop.

Comment: @JaccLawrence If my answer was helpful, please consider leaving an upvote and marking my answer as accepted it would really help boost my rep score (and gives you some rep as well)

Answer (score 0):

In your final line you have the function `F([x_vec0])`, this means within the function `F` the variable `x_vec = [x_vec0]`. You then pass this variable to the function `f1`, so within `f1`, `x = [x_vec0]`. Within `x[1]` can be found within `f1`. The problem is that `x` will never have a second entry. If `x_vec0 = [0,1]` (or some other array object such as an `np.ndarray`), then `[x_vec0] = [[0,1]]`, i.e. `[x_vec0][0] = [0,1]` and `[x_vec0][1]` does not exist.

I got all the information from the traceback (obviously I had to invent a value for `x_vec0`):

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d57a9d10dd94> in <module>
     80         return nu
     81 x_vec0 = np.array([1,2])
---> 82 print(rf_newton2d(F([x_vec0]),Jinv([x_vec0]),[2,3],10**-5, 5))

<ipython-input-4-d57a9d10dd94> in F(x_vec)
     16 # define matrix F(x) 2x1
     17 def F(x_vec):
---> 18     return [f1(x_vec),f2(x_vec)]
     19 
     20 #print(F([2,3]))

<ipython-input-4-d57a9d10dd94> in f1(x)
      9 
     10 def f1(x):
---> 11     return 2*(x[0]**3) - 6*(x[0]*(x[1]**2)) - 1
     12 
     13 def f2(x):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Without knowing the maths of Newton-Raphson roots I can't suggest what the fix is.